# Can I get geth.ipc if I use ganache-cli to deploy a default private test ethereum env

Tags: go-ethereum, ganache

When I test my golang code which subscribes/filter/parse log from a local ethereum test env built by myself, The way I communicate with eth is by using geth.ipc.

But another test env is based on ganache with which I am not familiar, therefore I can not find the geth.ipc to connect. I know I can still talk to ethereum via the HTTP port. But there came an err message like subscription is not supported by HTTP.

I just wonder if I can find that ipc file in ganache test env to keep using my code, or I should adopt to HTTP RPC connection by change the communication way a little bit.

Thanks in adv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using ganache you can use the websocket endpoint `ws://localhost:8545` to be able to subscribe to event logs